# no results found when loading Excel file mySQL

Tags: mysql, excel, csv

I am trying to load an excel file .XLSX, when running it shows Success, but no results were found. In the excel file there are results mainly 3 columns:
Region (text column)
2018M01 (decimal values)
2018M02 (decimal values)

My code is:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS book;

CREATE TABLE book (
    Region LONGTEXT,
    2018M01 decimal(4,2),
    2018M02 decimal(4,2)
);

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/BPerei23/Downloads/Book1.xlsx' 
REPLACE INTO TABLE book
CHARACTER SET Latin1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Can someone pls advice why its not loading properly? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LOAD DATA INFILE` doesn't handle Microsoft's proprietary .xlsx format for spreadsheets. Save the file as a .csv file and try again.

Comment: @OJones I tried this still no difference, it shows success but nothing loaded. It is a bit strange because it works on my Mac mySQL, but not on my windows mySQL

Comment: @user23456 This is the correct answer, and `LOAD DATA` won't be able to parse a binary Excel file.  There must be some other problem with your code.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen is there any way to load an Excel file directly ?

Comment: Note directly via MySQL, at least known of which I know.  The app languages such as Java and C# have libraries which can directly parse an Excel file, if you are open to that.